# XSLT Validate and Concatenate Multiple Variables

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have to validate and concatenate multiple variable after validating them.

```
<xsl:variable name="val1" select="//xpath"/>
<xsl:variable name="val2" select="//xpath"/>
<xsl:variable name="val3" select="//xpath"/>
<xsl:variable name="val4" select="//xpath"/>
<xsl:variable name="val5" select="//xpath"/>
```

Is there any template available for this or anyone can help me doing this.

**Update from comments**

I want to concatenate five values like this: `Address, Address1, City, State, Zipcode`. If `Address` is missing I'll get an output like this "`, address1, city, state, zipcode`". I want to get rid of that first comma.

```
<xsl:variable name="__add" select="translate(//*/text()[contains(., 'Address')]/following::td[contains(@class, 'fnt')][1], ',', '')"/>

<xsl:variable name="address">
    <xsl:for-each select="$__add | //*/text()[contains(., 'City')]/following::td[contains(@class, 'fnt')][1] | //*/text()[contains(., 'State')]/following::td[contains(@class, 'fnt')][1] | //*/text()[contains(., 'Pincode')]/following::td[contains(@class, 'fnt')][1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(', ', 1 div (position()!=1)), .)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: What kind of validation are you talking about here? Normally validation is something applied to the input document before you start executing the transformation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0: `string-join((Address, Address1, City, State, Zipcode), ',')`

In XSLT 1.0, provided you're outputting the results in document order:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Address | Address1 | City | State | Zipcode">
  <xsl:if test="position() != 1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If not in document order, then like many things in XSLT 1.0, it's probably rather tedious.

Answer (score 8):

XSLT has a function

```
concat(string, string, ...)
```

that you can use in the `select=` attribute of another variable

```
<xsl:variable name="vals" select="{concat($val1,$val2,$vl3,$val4,$val5)}"/>
```

or anywhere an attribute value template is allowed (in curly braces).

Comment: Thanks, but I want to validate each variable like whether they have a value or not and then concatenate.

Comment: What do you want to do if one or more is/are not valid?  We need more information on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: For example: I want to concatenate four values like this: Address, Address1, City, State, Zipcode. If address is missing i'll get an output like this ", address1, city, state, zipcode". I want to get rid of that first comma.

Comment: `xsl:variable/@select` can't be an AVT. That would need dynamic XPath evaluation...

Answer (score 1):

An XSLT 1.0 solution preserving the expression order (`xsl:sort` instruction) and using Becker's method (`substring()` second argument):

```
<xsl:for-each select="Address|Address1|City|State|Zipcode">
   <xsl:sort select="substring-before(
                        '|Address|Address1|City|State|Zipcode|',
                        concat('|',name(),'|')
                     )"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(
                            substring(
                               ', ',
                               1 div (position()!=1)
                            ),
                            .
                         )"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It's a pain that you can't use XSLT 2.0... Look how simple!

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="Address, Address1, City, State, Zipcode"
     separator=", "/>
```

**Note**: XPath 2.0 sequence has the implicit order of construction. Because XSLT 2.0 `xsl:value-of` instruction handle sequence, there is now a `@separator`.

Comment: I had doubts if to upvote and, though I did (+1 :)), it's a kind of code I wouldn't want to see in a big non-solo project :/

Comment: Though preserving the order is sometimes very handy.

Comment: @Flack: Maybe. But do note that there was some use of this idiom even here in SO.

Comment: @Alejandro, I myself prefer not to use OB method. Of course, I can't say it's wrong to use it at all :)

Comment: @Flack: Oh! About that, I completely agree. It was just as illustration... Although in an XPath 1.0 only enviroment, it might be handy

Comment: @Alejandro I have added my code where I'm using a variable, I'm not getting any output. Could you help me.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can be helful:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="vMyVars">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Address | Address1 | City | State | Zipcode" mode="vMyVars"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($vMyVars, -1, string-length($vMyVars))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="vMyVars"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[normalize-space()]" mode="vMyVars">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this XML:

```
<elems>
    <Address>test</Address>
    <Address1>test2</Address1>
    <City>test3</City>
    <State>test4</State>
    <Zipcode>test5</Zipcode>
</elems>
```

Result will be:

```
test, test2, test3, test4, test5
```

And to this XML:

```
<elems>
    <Address1>test2</Address1>
    <City>       </City>
    <State>test4</State>
    <Zipcode></Zipcode>
</elems>
```

Result will be:

```
test2, test4
```